# Reshape dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple headers that is set up as below. I would like to combine the row and column into one line. Any suggestions? I am able to bring down one header but not more.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df  = pd.read_csv('Sample_Cookbook4.csv',header=[0,1],index_col=[0])
df = df.stack(dropna=False)
df.index = df.index.get_level_values(0) + df.index.get_level_values(1)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Current Dataframe**

```
                  Header1     |        Header2      |
           xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4||xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4||xxx1|xxx2|xxx3|xxx4 |
ColX|ColY |ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD||ColD|ColE|ColF|ColG||ColH|ColI|ColJ|ColDK|
1   | ds  | 1  |    |+1  |-1  | .......................................
2   | dh  |  ..........................................................
3   | ge  |  ..........................................................
4   | ew  |  ..........................................................
5   | er  |  ..........................................................
```

**Output**

ds - Header 1 - xx1 - ColA: 1

ds - Header 1 - xx2 - ColB: ""

ds - Header 1 - xx2 - ColB: -1

Comment: Not sure I understand the output..

Comment: Perhaps `df.stack(level=[0,1,2])`?